# Is there a way to keep my email subdomain at mail.example.com?

Tags: domains, subdomain, email, gmail, mail

I've pointed it at the Google app servers, and unfortunately that means a redirect to `mail.google.com`. Is there a way to avoid that redirect and allow me to browse email at `mail.example.com`? Will I have to host my own mail server if I want that to happen?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have your domain name point to your Google Apps mail. If if that is correct, then add the following CNAME record to your domain's DNS settings:

```
Name/Host/Alias: mail
TTL: 3600
Record Type: CNAME
Value: ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

[Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/112038) is more information from Google.

Comment: No, sorry, there was another answer (and another discussion following it) that is now deleted unfortunately, but basically it works perfectly, it just redirects to `mail.google.com` when I go to `mail.mydomain.com`, and I was wondering if there was a way to avoid that redirect, either with Gmail or another email provider. Seems like it's not possible.